# Writing in Portuguese HTML - encoding?

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

I have simple HTML file , with alertbox .
The content in the alertbox is in Portuguese , as you know they have special characters for example:
espaço

but if I'll write this on my alertbox the output I'll see is this :
espaÃ§o

I have no idea what is the problem I tried to add this :

between the 
but didn't work , I'm using rackspace CDN as hosting if it is matters .

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The default encoding for web developement is UTF-8.
You should use that.

By deafult the web browsers use that encoding.

If you realy can't use UTF-8 maybe you can change your page charset.

from

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

to

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: I tried to use this <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
and it didn't work

Comment: @user3287288 what about UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the special characters.
1.Option: You can change the lang to the country code from Protugal.
`<html lang="??" >`

2.Option:

Maybe you can try to replace your  Portuguese character with the HTML code for that special character, take a look to this table of special characters and its HTML representation: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

The second is more secure.

Comment: hey , the problem is option 2 doesn't work on alert box

Comment: hmm.. can you regardless show the code?. Did you try the first option? with <html lang ="PT">